# Recursive feedback in Karplus-Strong Algo - arrows

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, arrows

I am trying to implement the simplest version of [Karplus-Strong algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karplus%E2%80%93Strong_string_synthesis) using [Euterpea](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Euterpea):

[image: schematic of KS algorithm]

My code:
0.7 seconds of white noise burst

```
burst :: AudSF () Double
burst = proc () -> do 
   burstEnv <- envLineSeg [1,1,0,0] [0.7, 0, 9.3] -< ()
   noise <- noiseWhite 42 -< ()
   outA -< burstEnv * noise
```

problematic part:

```
karplus :: AudSF Double Double
karplus = proc input -> do 
  rec  filtered <- filterLowPass -< (delayed, 2000)
       delayed <- delayLine 0.7 -< filtered + input      
  outA -< filtered + input
```

test1 function should create a file of 10 seconds with a few cycles:

```
test1 = outFile "test1.wav" 10 $ burst >>> karplus
```

As far as I know the feedback loop should run on and on and on.

The problem is the input is only delayed and filtered once. It's not fed to the loop again.

I suspect that the problem lies in my not understanding lazy evaluation or value passing.

Comment: Lazy evaluation can affect whether a program gets stuck in an infinite loop, but it cannot change a program that successfully does one thing into a program that successfully does another. Is the program stuck, or just wrong?

Comment: @dfeuer it's wrong. Output singal is not fed into the loop.

Comment: If it produces wrong output, you can rule out laziness as the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not lazy evaluation or recursive arrows; rather, it's that `filterLowPass` doesn't behave nice on `burst`: it becomes `NaN` after the burst finishes.

We can see that by running it e.g. in GHCi:

```
λ» take 15 $ drop 30870 $ Control.SF.SF.run (strip $ burst >>> arr (,2000) >>> filterLowPass) $ repeat ()
[0.17166330080286152,0.27722776378398983,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]
```

I strongly suspect it is because `burst` itself behaves strangely near its end:

```
λ» take 15 $ drop 30870 $ Control.SF.SF.run (strip $ burst) $ repeat ()
[0.5998949495013488,NaN,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,-0.0,0.0,-0.0,0.0]
```

My suggestion is to fix `burst` so that it doesn't generate a `NaN` at its end, and then see if that fixes everything. The 0/-0 oscillation is probably harmless.

**Attempt at fixing**

I have no idea about either Euterpea or sound synthesis; however, by using a very short, but non-0 transition time from 1 to 0 for `burstEnv`, I was able to get rid of the `NaN`s. By further reducing the length of the burst and the delay line, I think I got something which is close to the desired "string-like" sound:

```
burst :: AudSF () Double
burst = proc () -> do
   burstEnv <- envLineSeg [1,1,0,0] [0.01, 0.000001, 9.3] -< ()
   noise <- noiseWhite 42 -< ()
   outA -< burstEnv * noise

karplus :: AudSF Double Double
karplus = proc input -> do
    rec delayed <- delayLine 0.01 -< filtered + input
        filtered <- filterLowPass -< (delayed, 2000)
    outA -< filtered + input
```